# Web api gives 404 on IIS works on IISExpress

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using .net core 2.2 when I work with IISExpress and post man I have no problem but when I publish the project and try to connect to api throw IIS I get 404 error

Comment: Could you enable developers exception page, and disable the routing to `error` pages? This is most likely a 500 trying to redirect you to the `error` page which you don't have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Anton Said I had configured a custom error page that was not existed therefor I got error 404 after I change that by this line

```
  if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
```

I got error 500 internal server error and error detail that helped me resolve actual error